# Testing a while loop in python

Tags: python, testing

What is the best method for testing a method that looks like this

```
class Foo(object):

   is_running = False
   def run(self):
       self.is_running = True
       while self.is_running:
           do_some_work()
```

This is pretty standard code for a consumer, do work while the `is_running` flag is set.

But this is difficult to test because it's going to enter the loop and never come out unless I create a second thread to change `is_running` to false.

Are there any good strategies for testing this without spinning up a separate thread to run the code?

I haven't seen anything but I am thinking maybe the mock library would provide functionality that can return a `[True, True, False]` each time `is_running` is read but would that require me to change `is_running` from a member variable to a property or a method?

Comment: perhaps you can use `subprocess.Popen.wait()`...

Comment: Why not replace it with a full descriptor instead of just a property?

Comment: why not use coroutines: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: Try `threading.Timer` - it spins up the thread for you. This object looks like its supposed to run in a separate thread anyway, so unit testing it that way seems normal to me.

Comment: I'm with @tdelaney - if the class is designed to be used in conjunction with another thread, why not test it that way? Creating a thread to use for this sort of test would only take a few lines of code, so its not like it adds a ton of overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I think testing this method using threads is a perfectly viable approach, and probably the best solution. However, if you really want to avoid threads, you could convert `is_running` to a `property` and then use [`mock.PropertyMock`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock) to mock the `property`:

```
import mock
import time

class Foo(object):

   def __init__(self):
       self._is_running = False

   @property
   def is_running(self):
       return self._is_running

   @is_running.setter
   def is_running(self, val):
       self._is_running = val 

   def run(self):
       self._is_running = True  # Don't go through the property here.
       while self.is_running:
           print("in here")
           time.sleep(.5)


with mock.patch('__main__.Foo.is_running', new_callable=mock.PropertyMock,
                side_effect=[True, True, False]) as m:
    f = Foo()
    f.run()
```

Output:

```
in here
in here
<done>
```

I would say that changing your production implementation this much just to enable a specific method of testing is not worth it, though. Just have your test function create a thread to set `is_running` after some period of time.